# using LYX to write journal with given formatting

Tags: packages, lyx

In a way I am newbie to Lyx.
I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and installed full version of texlive 2012.

I am trying to work out to generate layout file for a journal (Royal Society of Chemistry, RSC) according the format (http://www.rsc.org/Publishing/Journals/guidelines/AuthorGuidelines/AuthoringTools/Templates/tex.asp).

This, RSC journal provide .tex, .bib, .bst, and .sty files. 
I am confused where to place the .sty files and how to use the given .tex with LYX .

I tried to place all the given files (.tex, .bst, .bib, .sty) in a folder in home directory and import the .tex file into LYX. I get error message when compile it with LYX.

Do I need to do any setting?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't need the `.sty` files at all: they are included as they are packages outside of the LaTeX kernel used by the template, but are in a modern TeX system like TeX Live 2012. Same goes for the `.bst` (which I maintain, and which is in TL2012).

Comment: The template provided contains a lot of LaTeX customization that makes LyX confused. I suggest working in LaTeX rather than making the effort to LyX-ify the template which certainly is possible but will take a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I agree with @vaettchen - LaTeX is not so different from LyX, once you separate the concepts of 'editor' and 'compiler'.

Comment: @vaettchen Do you want to write an answer so this can get off the unanswered list?

Comment: @cfr done - I'm not particularly proud of this answer but if it helps to clean up the list...

Comment: @vaettchen Thank you. And +1 gets it off the list and thanks you more concretely for your trouble ;). (Though it is only virtual concrete, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where probably using LaTeX directly is more adequate. Lyx is a convenient interface to LaTeX for people who don't want to be concerned with the "programming" their document, and it is very easy to use as long as it runs "out of the box".

Here, a lot of effort would need to go into making Lyx understand rsc template. It appears that using a decent LaTeX editor and writing the article in plain LaTeX is, under these circumstances, the better alternative.